# Proper architecture to serve several separate, unconnected multi-page websites under one single internet domain?

Tags: node.js, angular, routes, web-hosting

I own a humble one-server internet domain.

I am migrating from the Apache/php world to the node / angular / react world.

Within this domain, I have various separate projects.  One is about my city, another is about my high school, a third is my portfolio, and so on.

One project might be a static SPA, the other might be a huge and highly dynamic professional production-level multi-page app with several frameworks, database connections and the whole kitchen sink.

One might be in react, the other in angular.

In short, a very diverse tech stack distributed among encapsulated applications.

I'm at the thinking stage, where I am considering the right way to run all these apps in one machine, in one domain, the modern way.

In the old Apache days, you would run one instance of Apache and it would serve everything with no problem.

Should I structure my code folders all as child folders of the one domain website?

In this new world, if I have ten websites do I have to run ten instances of a daemon like this Option A:

```
One instance of node, or whatever daemon, serves and routes all MPAs:    
   daemon1       
   my-domain.com
      +--HighSchoolWebsite
      +--SanFranciscoWebsite
      +--PortfolioPage
```

Or should it be more like this Option B:

```
   daemon1
   +--HighSchoolWebsite

   daemon2
   +--SanFranciscoWebsite

   daemon3
   +--PortfolioPage
```

and if it is Option B, won't the daemons be listening at different ports?  I would have to tell people to go to a url with a port number, like mydomain.com/myportfolio:2452.  I've never seen this, so it must not be the way it's done, so what's the right way?

I have tried Googling this obviously but most answers tend to discuss MPAs for one single project, not SPA+MPA for several different projects.

Obviously I'm a beginner a bit lost at sea and would appreciate any tips, tricks, hints, rumors, etc.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gee, thanks to all the downvote fairies for being so helpful to someone just trying to learn.

In case anyone else finds themselves at a similar stage, the answer is a "process manager" + a "reverse proxy".

A process manager is like a command that permanently serves your apps.  It will keep your various apps running forever whether they be node, or php, or angular.  Each app can be assigned a nickname.  The process manager I chose was PM2.

A reverse proxy then maps the incoming requested url to the particular app listening on its chosen port.  The reverse proxy I used was nginx.

So, for example, let's say you have phpApp running on port 1943.  Let's say that in PM2 you nicknamed it pretty-happy-app.  During dev, you would visit

```
http://localhost:1943
```

to see your pretty-happy-php app running.

Since you want a) external visitor to visit without knowing the port, and in fact you want to b) hide the port for security reasons, you use a reverse proxy like nginx.

You configure nginx to map the url to the port.  During dev, assuming you're using your local machine, the configuration would be something like:

```
http://localhost/pretty-happy-app  ---> localhost:1943
```

Once you go public, nginx would map like this:

```
http://your-domain.com/pretty-happy-app  ---> your-public-machine:1943
```

I hope this helps someone in the future, not like the too-cool-for-school downvote fairies.